# Why failed transactions are not shown in Horizon in any way?

Tags: horizon, fees

Anything I can get of the Horizon about the failed transactions is their count in a ledger. No other info is shown about them. Currently, no one can calculate lumen balance using horizon only because of the absence of fees for failed transactions. Is there any development plans for failed transactions to amend situations like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizon can ingest failed transactions but it's turned off by default. You can enable it by:

- Setting env variable: `INGEST_FAILED_TRANSACTIONS=true`,
- Setting param switch: `--ingest-failed-transactions`.